Was Harrison Ford a cameo in I, Robot?
I recently watched the 2004 film I, Robot starring Will Smith. There's a bar scene where as the camera moves closer to the main character we get a glimpse of another patron of the bar who looks, IMHO, remarkably like Harrison Ford.
IMDB doesn't seem to mention it nor can I find anything online.
I found the scene on YouTube from which the screen shot below was taken from.


I do see the resemblance but if you showed me that picture and asked me who it was I wouldn't say "Harrison Ford". I don't think that's him.

Frankly, the answer to basically any such "is this random dude who looks completely random a high-profile actor cameo noone ever noticed before?" question is a resounding "no, no it isn't, why would it be?". The fact that you checked IMDb is commendable, the unwillingness to just accept what you found there in light of this guy looking nothing like Ford in the first place...not so much. ;-)

I have checked the details over wiki as well as tried to check star cast of the movie directly
But haven't found anything related to Harrison Ford's involvement in the movie. Also, nothing was documented or confirmed by the filmmakers or cast.
So It seems like only a look-alike coincidently there.

TBF, it really looks almost nothing like Ford; his cheekbones are not so prominent, his chin is more rounded and his nose is not as sharply pointed.
